# Looping through columns with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm trying to loop through columns and rows of a csv file but only getting the first row result.

this is my csv layout 2 columns with rows

```
name        total
subtitle1
name1       65%
name2       65%
name3       65%
name4       65%
total       60%
subtitle2
name1       65%
name2       65%
name3       65%
name4       65%
total       60%
subtitle3
name1       65%
name2       65%
name3       65%
name4       65%
total       60%
subtitle4
name1       65%
name2       65%
name3       65%
name4       65%
total       60%
```

```js
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.csv',
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "text",
 contentType: "text/csv",
 success: function (data) {
  var columns = data.split(/\n/);
  var column1 = columns[0].split(/\,/);
  var column2 = columns[1].split(/\,/);
  var data = {};
  for(var i=0; i<column1.length; i++) {
   data[column1[i].trim()] = column2[i].trim();
   console.log(data);
  }      
 }
});
```

Comment: Why are you sending `contentType: "text/csv"`? That's the type of the parameters, not the response.

Comment: There are no commas in your data, why are you splitting on that?

Comment: You aren't looping through all the rows. `columns[0]` is the first row, `columns[1]` is the second row. You're ignoring all the other rows.

Comment: How do I go through all data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you've splitted the file into `columns` which is actually rows and not columns, then you've broken down the first and second **row** into two columns - one from the first row and one from the second.

What you should do is first split by rows, then for each row - split by columns:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.csv',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "text/csv",
    success: function (data) {
        // Splitting the file into rows
        var rows = data.split(/\n/);
        for (var rowIndex in rows)
        {
            // For every row - split it into columns
            var columns = rows[rowIndex].split(/,/);
            for (var colIndex in columns)
            {
                var colValue = columns[colIndex].trim();
                // here you have the colValue to play with
                console.log(colValue);
            }           
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I want to access the subtitle and print that in html how do I do that? $(".subtitle").each(function( index, value ) { 
          value.innerHTML = data.colValue;
      });

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're looking for, plus it seems that it's a different question.

Comment: With your answer code I'm getting all data which is great now I what to go through the data and print it on my html page. for example if i want to print the subtitles only in a h3 tag in the past I used .each function like this $(".subtitle").each(function( index, value ) { value.innerHTML = data.colValue; });

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the wrong thing. `data.split('\n')` returns an array of rows, but you're not looping over that.

Loop over all the rows. In this loop, split the line at whitespace (there are no commas in your data).

```
var result = {};
var rows = data.split('\n');
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var columns = rows[i].split(/\s+/);
    if (columns.length > 1) { // skip the subtitle rows
        result[columns[0]] = columns[1];
    }
}
```